How to access to file attached to a message in a team channel
I use the following (not redacted) code to post a message (with a file) in a channel:
string teamId = "sqdqssqsq";
string channelId = "sdfdsfgdsgsfsdfdsf";
string fileName = "newfile2.txt";

var ffs = await gc.Teams[teamId].Channels[channelId].FilesFolder.GetAsync();
var d = await gc.Groups[teamId].Drive.GetAsync();

Stream file = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("fluctuat nec mergitur"));
DriveItem dif = await gc.Drives[d.Id].Items[ffs.Id].
    ItemWithPath(fileName).
    Content.PutAsync(file);

string attId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
ChatMessage cm = new ChatMessage {
    Subject = "another file",
    Body = new ItemBody {
        ContentType = BodyType.Html,
        Content = $"<p>Attached is the new file.</p><attachment id=\"{attId}\"/>"
    },
    Attachments = new List<ChatMessageAttachment> {
        new ChatMessageAttachment {
            Id = attId,
            ContentType = "reference",
            ContentUrl = dif.WebUrl,
            Name = dif.Name,
        }
    }
};

var r = await gc.Teams[teamId].Channels[channelId].Messages.PostAsync(cm);

In Teams application I can:

read the message in the channel,
access the file in the Files tab of the channel,
access the file from the message by clicking on "see in the browser" (in the actions associated to the file in the message)

But I can't access the file from the message by clicking on it or trying to download it. Teams says: This element may not exist or not be available anymore.
What do I make wrong ? That is what must I do to activate the attached file in the message ?
